# Swagger is Adding Placeholder Text to the Url in Requests sent by the Try It Out Feature

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swagger and SwaggerUi (via the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore Nuget package) for my WebAPI project.

The problem that I am having is that the UI is not forming the request properly for the Try It Out feature. For example, my API has a nullable `long` in the method signature at the server. That parameter is called `modifiedSince`.

When I click execute, without a value in the modifiedSince text input, the following Url is hit `https://localhost:44348/v1/Complication/%7BmodifiedSince%7D`

It is picking up the Placeholder text and including that in the URL (inside html-encoded curly braces).

On another endpoint, I have two parameters and the URL is meant to look like this: `https://localhost:44348/v1/Logbook/37193/Entry/2121321`

But when I click the Try It Out button, SwaggerUi sends `https://localhost:44348/v1/Logbook/37193/Entry/%7BentryId%7D?entryId=2121321` and as a result, a null value comes into my server's method for the entryId parameter.

Again, the placeholder of the relevant text input is being added to the url.

I upgraded from 2.5.0 to 3.0.0 in a bid to fix the issue. But it is still occurring.

An example of a Controller action which the Swagger API is hitting is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Logbooks of user.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="modifiedSince"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <response code="200">Logbooks assigned to the user</response>
/// <response code="204">No logbooks assigned to the user</response>
/// <response code="400">Error state. Error message included in payload.</response>        
/// <response code="403">Authentication required.</response>        
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]/{modifiedSince?}")]
[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<IEnumerable<LogbookDto>>), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(204)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<string>), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ApiResponse<string>), 403)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logbook(long? modifiedSince)
{
    var logbookDtos = default(IEnumerable<LogbookDto>);

    if (await AuthorizeAsync(User, IdentityConstants.PolicyNames.RacsUser) &&
        await Execute(async () => logbookDtos = await _mediator.Send(
            new GetLogbooksQuery
            {
                UserId = _currentUser.UserId
                //LastConfigChange = NULL
            }))
            )
    {
        if (logbookDtos.Any())
            return Ok(new ApiResponse<IEnumerable<LogbookDto>> { Data = logbookDtos, Outcome = new OperationOutcome { Error = false, Message = "" } });

        return NoContent();
    }

    return ErrorResponse(new ApiResponse<string> { Data = Errors, Outcome = new OperationOutcome { Error = true, Message = "" } });
}
```

Here is a pic from Chrome dev tools to depict what is happening:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on? Have I missed a config somewhere?

Comment: Please share the code for the controller you are having problems with.

Comment: Have you tested removing the nullable from the parameter(s) ?

Comment: @HelderSepu Sorry for delay. I'm in another timezone. I removed the nullable from the Action method's parameter and the url was formed properly `https://localhost:44348/v1/Logbook` . I will now update the question with the Controller code. Removing the parameter was just a troubleshooting technique, I'm hoping, as it does not really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from the comments:

If it works when you remove the nullable that points to a bug in swashbuckle, you should report it: 
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new

The only thing that I'm a bit fuzzy is that from a JSON Schema perspective a `nullable` does not necessarily imply `not required`...
 You can have field required and allow null as a value

There are some things that C# does that do not directly translate to something in swagger, my recommendation remove the nullable, maybe instead you can use a default value, something like:
`public async Task<IActionResult> Logbook(long modifiedSince = -1)`

And handle the default case in code

Comment: I think that work around with the default value might be adequate. The issue with nullables may be a limitation of Swagger itself - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/172